# How to create admin without creating admin table into the database and with one login route and controller into the same page?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two controller classes one for custom signin and one for my items.
Custome controller class that authenticates all the users

```
class SigninController extends Controller
{
    public function getSigninRequest(Request $request)
    {


        $this->validate($request,[
               'email'=>'required|email',
               'password'=>'required'
        ]);

        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->input('email'),
                          'password'=>$request->input('password')],
                           $request->has('remember')))
        {
            return redirect()->route('admin.index');
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('fail','Authentication failed!');
    }


}

User Model class for normal users and admin

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    const ADMIN_TYPE = 'admin';
    const DEFAULT_TYPE ='default';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }
      public function isAdmin()
      {
          return $this->type=== self::ADMIN_TYPE;
      }


}
 user database migration in which I added type row
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('type')->default('default');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Route web.php. I want to pass all data with one login route

Auth::routes();

Route::post('login',[
            'uses'=>'SigninController@getSigninRequest',
            'as'=>'auth.signin'
]);
```

I want to create admin user who can add/delete and edit items even those items are created by normal users who can only add/edit and delete their own items only. So, after login, all users must be redirected to the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we believe you have a table in database that it's name in Users and model User and it has 3 columns with this values

```
id,    name,    password,    role
1      jack     123456       admin
2      bob      123456       user
```

so you have a form that should login just with name
and you have a controller with name UserController

this is the update function

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = /Auth::guard('your_guard')->user();
    if($user->role == 'admin')
    {
       //update rows from everyOne, because this user is admin
       $all_users_information = User::all();     //you let him do everyThing with all users table
    }
    elseif($user->role != 'admin')
    {
        //update just himself information and don't let him to access others informations
        $just_your_information = User::find($user->id);    //do something with just himself information
    }
}
```

i hope you can use it

Answer (score 0):

you can use a role column in users table in database that can be 'admin' | 'user' or 1|0 or something else that you want.
so you can use a single form for login,
after login you can use the role column of the user that logined in
if it was the 'admin' so he can delete or update all informations
if the user that logined in now, was not admin then he can only update or delete his own informations

you can check it with this code

```
$user_role = /Auth::guard('your_guard')->user()->role;
```

Comment: and if `$user_role` was not admin you redirect him to another page

Comment: Thanks Reza.can u plz provide me any examples or any blog.So that I can check.

Comment: @yasir Sorry, i don't have any example. but i can create a simple example for you in next answer

Comment: $user_role = /Auth::guard('your_guard')->user()->role; what is ('your_guard')

Comment: every guard is for one type of user, in this case that you want don't have a new table in database , so you are using the default guard for all type of users. the default guard is 'web' you should write this: `$user_role = /Auth::guard('web')->user()->role;`